# Installing python on Azure App Service -- which tools can I use?

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created an App Service on Linux in Azure portal, hoping to use if as a managed `Node.js` server. A simple test app works but when coming to install `bip32`, or other `web3` related packages I get the following error:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

The obvious next step is to install `Python`, but the machine doesn't have any of the usual tools used for installing. No `apt-get`. No `yum`.

Any other options I could use for installing packages?

Comment: It seems that there is no python runtime for it. Maybe you can choose the python runtime when you create the web app on Azure.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT I need to run a `Node.js` app on it. So I would need to install `npm`. But I'm unable to install anything. No `apt`. No `yum`. No `rpm`.

Comment: Azure Web App has the built-in runtime for NodeJS. You can try to use it.

Comment: You can specify the NodeJS runtime version by setting an application setting in the App Service on the Portal. Check out this link for supported version and more info. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro)

Answer (score 3):

For your issue, you could have something misunderstand. The Azure Web App Service just allow you to manage your application, do not allow you to change the running environment in the Service Plan. For example, like that, you want to install tools such as apt and npm in it.

Azure provides some built-in runtime to Web App. Just like Node.js x, Python x, etc. You can choose an appropriate one to use. Even if there is no one suitable for you, you can make your application into a Docker image and create the Web App from it. Of curse, you should make sure your application can work well in the image and you can install the tools which you need. For more details, see [Use a custom Docker image for Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image). Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: I created a machine with Python runtime (no option for choosing 2.7, which is what my packages need) and there was no npm on the machine. I played around a bit trying to install it but honestly this process doesn't inspire confidence.

Comment: Perhaps, you can try the custom Docker image, you can install python 2.7 in it in the base image ubuntu or others.

Comment: I moved on to other options.

Comment: @Eddy So what choice do you move to?